# How to find a key by value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Javascript and react. I have a react app with the following array and a function to find a key inside the array. I'm providing the search value as parameter and I need to find the key which has the search value. **`I have three user roles as client, admin and manager`**. I'm doing the code as follows

Array:

```
{
  client:[{ id:1, name:"Adam" },
         { id:2, name:"Mon" },
         { id:3, name:"Sara" }],
  admin:[{ id:4, name:"Jake" },
         { id:5, name:"Jon" },
         { id:6, name:"Sean" }],
  manager:[{ id:7, name:"Doe" },
         { id:8, name:"Matt" },
         { id:9, name:"Mark" }]
}
```

**I need to find the user role by given id**. This is what I tried.

Component:

```
roleCheck = (searchId) => {
    var roles = this.state.array;
    Object.keys(roles).forEach(role => {
      Object.keys(role).forEach(user => {
        if (user.id === searchId){
          return role;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

The result is always **Undefined**. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you please create an example code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning any thing from you function. You can change your coe in following manner

```
roleCheck = (searchId) => {
    var roles = this.state.array;
    let output = 'Not found'
    Object.keys(roles).forEach(role => {
      Object.keys(role).forEach(user => {
        if (user.id === searchId){
           output = role
        }
      });
    });
   return output;
  }
```

Or alternatively You can use `find` and `some`

```js
let data = {client:[{ id:1, name:"Adam" },{ id:2, name:"Mon" },{ id:3, name:"Sara" }],admin:[{ id:4, name:"Jake" },{ id:5, name:"Jon" },{ id:6, name:"Sean" }],manager:[{ id:7, name:"Doe" },{ id:8, name:"Matt" },{ id:9, name:"Mark" }]}

let role = (searchId) => {
  return Object.keys(data).find(key => {
    return data[key].some(({id})=> id === searchId)
  })
}

console.log(role(6))
console.log(role(60))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` will only return from the function given to `forEach` and not the `checkRole` function.

You could instead use a combination of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to figure out what role the person with the `searchId` has:

```js
const data = {
  client: [
    { id: 1, name: "Adam" },
    { id: 2, name: "Mon" },
    { id: 3, name: "Sara" }
  ],
  admin: [
    { id: 4, name: "Jake" },
    { id: 5, name: "Jon" },
    { id: 6, name: "Sean" }
  ],
  manager: [
    { id: 7, name: "Doe" },
    { id: 8, name: "Matt" },
    { id: 9, name: "Mark" }
  ]
};

function roleCheck(searchId) {
  return Object.keys(data).find(key => {
    return data[key].some(person => person.id === searchId);
  });
}

console.log(roleCheck(8));
```

Answer (score 1):

using the https://underscorejs.org/ library us can do this

```
var hash = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
};

(_.invert(hash))[1]; // => 'foo'
```

you can put this into your loop

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check if a JavaScript Object has a key is using `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
let c = {"name": "John", "id": 12};
c.hasOwnProperty("name") // true
```